# Upload Date and time from firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a collection named Data where the user data is stored. While displaying the data i want to display the date and time it was uploaded on the server.
Is it possible to get the date and time it was uploaded on Firestore? If yes how to do it?

P.S. I don't want to have two fields for date and time in my collection that's why looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't expose the date/time a document was created, so you will at the very least have to add one field for that.

But the entire value can be stored in a single field of [type `Timestamp`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/4.0.2/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html), which identifies a point in time. If you want to set a field to the current timestamp on the server, you can do:

```
collection
      .add({
        'full_name': fullName, // John Doe
        'company': company, // Stokes and Sons
        'age': age // 42
        'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      })
```